# SQLCMD não executa comando após instalação silenciosa do SQL Server com o Inno Setup

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch, inno-setup

Tenho um script do **Inno Setup** que provê ao usuário a instalação do SQL Server 2012, e após concluída, ele deveria restaurar uma base de dados em um caminho especificado, para poder 'componentizar' meu instalador, coloquei como opção restaurar o banco de dados, e quando marcada essa opção, o instalador vai executar um arquivo **.bat**, que vai executar um comando `SQL` via  `sqlcmd` e restaurar o banco de dados através de um arquivo **.bak**

Meu problema é que a restauração do banco de dados não ocorre quando solicitada no instalador, e não consegui encontrar o motivo disso.

Segue script do Inno Setup:

```
[Files]
;SQL EXPRESS
Source: "Setup\SQL Server 2012 Express\SQL2012EXPR_x86.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: 
deleteafterinstall onlyifdoesntexist; Components: PDVM8Servidor

Source: "Setup\SQL Server 2012 Express\SQL2012EXPR_x64.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: 
deleteafterinstall onlyifdoesntexist; Components: PDVM8Servidor

;Banco de dados
Source: "Dependencias\Banco de dados\PDVM8.bak"; DestDir: "{sd}\PDVM8"; Components: 
PDVM8Servidor/BancoDeDadosVazio

Source: "Dependencias\Banco de dados\sql-pdvm8.bat"; DestDir: "{sd}\PDVM8"; Components: 
PDVM8Servidor/BancoDeDadosVazio


[Run]

;SQL EXPRESS
Filename: "{app}\SQL2012EXPR_x86.exe"; Parameters: "/QS /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER 
/IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /INDICATEPROGRESS /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL,AS,RS,IS,Tools 
/AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /SQLSVCACCOUNT=""NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"" 
/SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=builtin\administrators /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=true /TCPENABLED=1 /NPENABLED=1 
/SECURITYMODE=SQL /UpdateEnabled=false /SAPWD=IWTI3K"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; Flags: runasoriginaluser 
shellexec waituntilterminated; StatusMsg: "Instalando SQL Server 2012 Express 32-bits..."; Check: 
"not IsWin64"; MinVersion: 0,6.1; Components: PDVM8Servidor;


Filename: "{app}\SQL2012EXPR_x64.exe"; Parameters: "/QS /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER 
/IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /INDICATEPROGRESS /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL,AS,RS,IS,Tools 
/AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /SQLSVCACCOUNT=""NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"" 
/SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=builtin\administrators /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=true /TCPENABLED=1 /NPENABLED=1 
/SECURITYMODE=SQL /UpdateEnabled=false /SAPWD=IWTI3K"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; Flags: runasoriginaluser 
shellexec waituntilterminated; StatusMsg: "Instalando SQL Server 2012 Express 64-Bits..."; Check: 
IsWin64;       MinVersion: 0,6.1; Components: PDVM8Servidor;  

Filename: "{sd}\PDVM8\sql-pdvm8.bat"; Parameters: "install";  Flags: runasoriginaluser shellexec 
waituntilterminated; MinVersion: 0,6.1; Components: PDVM8Servidor/BancoDeDadosVazio;


[Dirs]
Name: "{sd}\PDVM8"; permissions: everyone-modify admins-full; Components: PDVM8Servidor
```

Segue script **sql-pdvm8.bat** que restaura o banco de dados:

```
    @echo *******************************************************
    @echo. 
    @echo *** Restaurando banco de dados vazio... ***
    @echo.
    @echo *******************************************************

    timeout /t 10 /nobreak

    sqlcmd -E -S . -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [PDVM8] FROM DISK='C:\PDVM8\PDVM8.bak' WITH RECOVERY"

    exit

    Pause
    EXIT /B
```

Considerações:

- Se eu executar o arquivo .bat diretamente na pasta, **funciona**
- Se eu executar o instalador, instalar o SQL server, e rodar o instalador pela segunda vez, **funciona**, o banco é restaurado.
- Se eu executar o instalador, cancelar a instalação do SQL Server, e forçar a execução da segunda etada, que seria restaurar o banco, **funciona**, o banco é restaurado.
- Se eu executar alguma outra função no `sqlcmd` que não seja essa, mas nos mesmos moldes (após a instalação do SQL Server, fazer uma chamada a um arquivo .bat, que executa uma função via `sqlcmd`), **funciona**
- Já tentei executar uma procedure com a tag **AfterInstall** do Inno, mas o banco também não restaura.
- Analisando eu vejo que o arquivo .bat é de fato chamado e aberto, o comando de restauração é executado, mas nada acontece, o banco não é restaurado.
- Não coloquei o código 100% completo do **Inno Setup**, pois ele é muito extenso. Tudo que diz respeito ao problema está na postagem do código acima.

O código só não funciona quando é uma primeira instalação do SQL Server, e na sequência a restauração do banco de dados, e pelo que vejo está tudo ok.
Grato desde já por qualquer dica que possa me ajudar a resolver isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema estava na execução do arquivo **.bat**. Com ajuda da comunidade, dei uma olhada nesta questão
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324386/debugging-non-working-batch-file-or-command-executed-from-inno-setup-installer
e consegui "Debuggar" a execução do arquivo.
Durante a execução, o comando SQLCMD não era reconhecido, e por isso o banco não era restaurado.
Para resolver, precisei fazer modificações no script do **Inno Setup** e também do arquivo **.bat**.

No script do Inno, o component responsável por executar a restauração do banco de dados ficou assim:

```
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/C ""{sd}\PDVM8\sql-pdvm8.bat"" install"; Flags: runasoriginaluser shellexec waituntilterminated; MinVersion: 0,6.1; Components: PDVM8Servidor;
```

E o arquivo **.bat**:

```
@echo *******************************************************
@echo. 
@echo *** Restaurando banco de dados vazio... ***
@echo.
@echo *******************************************************

cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn

sqlcmd -E -S . -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [PDVM8] FROM DISK='C:\PDVM8\PDVM8.bak' WITH 
RECOVERY"

EXIT /B
```

No final das contas, o problema maior era que eu deveria executar o comando dentro do caminho relativo onde o SQLCMD.exe fica instalado.